# Error installing sparklyr package

Tags: r

I'm getting this error when installing sparklyr package on my local machine:

I also tried installing the development version but get the same error.

```
install.packages("sparklyr")
 trying URL 
'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.3/sparklyr_0.5.3.tgz'
 Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1025493 bytes (1001 KB)

 downloaded 1001 KB
 The downloaded binary packages are in
/var/folders/m8/y4hvcvrx4233n10636g64mlh0000gn/T//Rtmp12G7T0/downloaded_packages
library(sparklyr)
Error : object 'sql_build' not found whilst loading namespace 'sparklyr'
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sparklyr’
```

When I try installing the dev version I get a different error:

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/sparklyr") 

Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/sparklyr@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/rstudio/sparklyr/zipball/master       
Installing sparklyr
 '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ 
--no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD  \
 INSTALL  \
'/private/var/folders/m8/y4hvcvrx4233n10636g64mlh0000gn/T
/Rtmp12G7T0/devtools258834121166/rstudio-sparklyr-5817985'  \
--library='/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library' --
install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘sparklyr’ ...
** R
** inst
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (sparklyr)
 > library(sparklyr)
 Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
 lazy-load database 

'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/
sparklyr/R/sparklyr.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sparklyr’
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Best,

Albit

Comment: Which version of R are you using? I have no trouble with version 3.3.2 and 3.3.3. Have you read the [README](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sparklyr/README.html)? Also try to reinstall `dplyr`.

Comment: Hey Therkel. Thanks for the reply. I'm using version 3.3.3. I tried reinstalling dplyr and then installing sparcklyr but I get the same error. I asked in Github below is the conversation thread with Kevin and Mr. Wickham: It looks like in the factoring of dplyr the sql_build() function has moved to a separate package, dbplyr, and so we need to import it from there.
@hadley: will dplyr import and re-export sql_build(), or should we now be importing it from dbplyr instead?Hadley: Why are you using sql_build()? It's not an obvious call so I thought it would be ok to move the generic into dbplyr.

Comment: I do not know how to proceed from here.

Comment: This was solved by installing dplyr development version using the following code: if (packageVersion("devtools") < 1.6) {
  install.packages("devtools")
}
devtools::install_github("hadley/lazyeval")
devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")